# CREATE command denied to user - Can you please answer to change any permission to allow my PHP-My-Admin to pass the below SQL command codes?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm not great programmer but happen to create a MySql table through SQL command from PHP-My-Admin. The MySQL command as follows:

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `login`.`users` (

 `user_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT  'auto incrementing user_id of each user, unique index',
 `user_name` VARCHAR( 64 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT  'user''s name, unique',
 `user_password_hash` VARCHAR( 255 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT  'user''s password in salted and hashed format',
 `user_email` VARCHAR( 64 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT  'user''s email, unique',
 `user_active` TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0' COMMENT  'user''s activation status',
 `user_activation_hash` VARCHAR( 40 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT  'user''s email verification hash string',
 `user_password_reset_hash` CHAR( 40 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT  'user''s password reset code',
 `user_password_reset_timestamp` BIGINT( 20 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT  'timestamp of the password reset request',
 `user_rememberme_token` VARCHAR( 64 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT  'user''s remember-me cookie token',
 `user_failed_logins` TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0' COMMENT  'user''s failed login attemps',
 `user_last_failed_login` INT( 10 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT  'unix timestamp of last failed login attempt',
 `user_registration_datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `user_registration_ip` VARCHAR( 39 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0.0.0.0',
PRIMARY KEY (  `user_id` ) ,
UNIQUE KEY  `user_name` (  `user_name` ) ,
UNIQUE KEY  `user_email` (  `user_email` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =1 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT =  'user data'
```

But MySQL replied me like the below:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>   #1142 - CREATE command denied to user 'a5175979_admin'@'localhost' for table 'users'

Can you please tell me, how to change any permission to allow my PHP-My-Admin to pass the above SQL command to create a table called "users" ?.

Comment: Removed the SQL Server tag, since this question doesn't relate with it

Comment: RTFM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in PhpMyAdmin

1. Click on privileges link.
2. Select your username.
3. Click on "Check All" permissions link.
4. Click on Go button.

read wiki https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/user_management

Comment: In shared hosting, they are not allowing customers to change the permissions by themselves. So, there is no privilege link in PhpMyAdmin home page.